# Dynamic part of web app based on REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, template-engine

We have web application which sends REST API request and change the DOM after request is completed. It is all done in jQuery with AJAX calls. But the problem is, all of the dynamic parts of a page has a slight delay to get updated on page refresh. It's like you first see the static elements and then immediately it gets updated. It is noticeable quite a lot.

We wait for `$(document).ready` so I think that is the issue. Is there a better way of updating HTML before it gets rendered so the user won't notice the change?

Not to mention, most of the data are cached in `sessionStorage` so it could be read without REST call.

I searched a little bit but I'm not quite sure, do I need a client-side template engine for this? Like `Mustache.js`?

Comment: how you render the html once the data is received isn't going to change asynchronous ajax delay issues. If data is already in storage that will have huge impact though

Comment: @charlietfl, as I said, the data are cached in `sessionStorage`. So for the initial load it is OK to see the delay but even when I read from `sessionStorage`, I still see the problem.

Comment: keep in mind you can get the data from storage before `document.ready`. You won't be able to render it until DOM is loaded but that might cut some time down if the data is large

Comment: If you still have the delay after changing to get the data prior to `document.ready` then your problem is probably in your rendering code, so please post that somewhere on fiddle so we can take a look

Comment: use a modal by default and hide it once you've rendered.

Comment: could also be a data size issue. Maybe it needs to be partitioned differently in storage

Comment: @unobf, let's say I have a string in `sessionStorage` and I want it to be rendered as `<span> $mystring </span>` somewhere in my html. How do I do it before `$document.ready`?

Comment: @charlietfl, it's just a string less than 20 chars.

Comment: Post some code before this gets into a whole lot of comments about unknowns

Comment: You cannot do that directly, but you can create all of the DOM elements, cache a reference to them somewhere and then when `document.ready` fires, you add them to the appropriate part of the page

Comment: tiny string like that won't matter when you retrieve it. Sounds like you have a heavy page then that takes a while to get to `ready` or you are using `onload` that won't fire until images are loaded

Comment: @charlietfl, yes. The page is heavy. That is my question. Is there any way better than `onload` or `document.ready`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it it possible to completely avoid delays caused by ajax requests. You could possibly put some request out of $(document).ready and place it in a head section:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       // some javascipt here, $.getJSON etc.
   </script>
</head>
```

In this case you have to look out for selecting elements that are not rendered yet (this could cause some unpleasent errors).

Finally I would recommend you to use some loading gif and animations of loaded elements in order to increase user experience. Take a look for example at AngularJS and its animation features here: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_12

Answer (score 1):

If all you're worried about is the noticeable change when the page updates, you could put everything inside your body tag inside a container div and give it `display:none;`. Display a loading image on page load then show the container div when the Ajax request is complete.